# Is it possible for an extension to know what event listeners are registered by another extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I think the title says it all. Suppose I have an extension X which has event listeners for some event(s). Is it possible for another extension, say Y, to get the list of all those event listeners ?

Comment: In addition to Xan's comment, wanting to know who's listening is generally a design smell. The Observer/Listener patterns are attractive because each side can remain isolated from knowledge about the other. By induction, one can also conclude that listeners shouldn't know about peer listeners. (And if OP's response is "yeah but I want to know anyway," then for privacy reasons this capability would be a bug in the platform. An extension shouldn't get to learn which other extensions are in the user's profile.)

Comment: Ya. I'm probably trying to do something impossible and stupid. Glad to know that this cannot be done. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can get the list of event listeners on a specific element, as explained by this post:
[How to find event listeners on a DOM node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node)

But Chrome extensions are made to be invisible, the page cannot detect that an extension inserted a content script inside of it.  Extensions are basically closed off, and no other page, or extension, can catch a glimpse of what goes on within another extension's content scripts.  So You can try, but i severely doubt it to be possible.

Comment: OP probably means Chrome events like `chrome.downloads.onCreated` and such.